# Помогите решить проблему c отображениям категории WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

есть вот такой код для отображения категорий в WordPress

```
<div class="site-catalog">
    <div class="site-catalog-ct nw">
        <h2><?php echo get_field('catalog_title')?></h2>
        <div class="site-catalog-tabs">
            <div class="site-catalog-tabs-menu">
                <?php foreach ($catalog_items as $key => $item) { ?>
                    <button type="button" data-tab="products-<?php echo $item['category']->term_id; ?>" class="site-catalog-tabs-menu-item <?php if(!$key) { ?>is--active<?php } ?>"><?php echo $item['category']->name; ?></button>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
```

только вот при удалении категории остаются пустые места при наведении которых появляются стили, но не отображаеься категории,

даже когда добавляешь категории они не обновляются, и не добавляется в меню.

что не так в ней, и почему она не работает корректно?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что у вас находиться в catalog_items? Можно посмотреть инициализацию?

Comment: $catalog_items = get_field('catalog_items'); Я вас правильно понял?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что вы делаете:

1. Вывод данных без проверки на существование значений

```
<?php

$cat_title = get_field('catalog_title');

if($cat_title) : ?>
    <h2><?php echo $cat_title; ?></h2>
<?php endif; ?>
```

2. Это остается не пустое место, а тег `<button>`, зачем категории брать в тег `<button>`?

Хотя, судя по атрибуту `data-tab=""` нам остается только догадываться, что эти кнопки нужны для переключения какой-то фильтрации.

```
<?php foreach ($catalog_items as $item) : ?>
    <button type="button" data-tab="products-<?php echo $item->term_id; ?>" class="site-catalog-tabs-menu-item">
        <?php esc_html_e($item->name); ?>
    </button>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```